# Was Elohim programmed to do this?

Tags: video-games, talos-principle

In Talos Principle, Elohim

> actively tries to prevent the PC from completing their function.

Now this could be read as either a self-aware AI

> trying to save its life

or as a built-in function of the system to

> deliberately make the PC defy Elohim as a necessary step to personhood.

Is there any concrete indication either in-game or out of game that it is one over the other, or possibly a third explanation? Or I suppose it could be both.

Comment: For people unfamiliar with video game jargon: "PC" = "player character" = "the character that the player controls."

Comment: Thank you, I meant to put that in but wasn't sure if people would be annoyed if I did.

Comment: Especially on Sci-Fi there are people with a variety of different knowledge bases, more information never hurts anyone. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is both, as confirmed on twitter by Jonas Kyratzes (Writer and designer on Talos):

@JonasKyratzes

> question on Talos: was elohim blocking the pc to try to save his "life"? Or a built in function to ensure elohi is defied as a necessary ascension step?

Replying to @LifetimeAthlete

> Both. He was intended to challenge the AI to defy him, but he took it too far out of fear (as seen by what he did to the characters in Road to Gehenna). He tried to cheat, essentially.

Final answer:

> So basically Elohim was programmed to challenge the PC, but out of fear of his own demise tried to cheat and end the PC/AI.

Since you hid the question in spoilers, I did likewise with the answers, although the game is a few years old now.

Comment: I thought it was still recent enough, and enough of a major spoiler, that it was worth the spoiler quotes. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Broklynite - No worries. :)